# Looking for verification of related rates logic!

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm working through a really interesting problem about related rates here and I'm pretty sure I've got it figured out.  But I'd like to get an expert's opinion on my method here:

*"Sand is falling into a conical pile at a rate of 7.2 cubic feet/second.  The base is always approximately 3/7 the height of the pile. When the pile is 13 feet high, what's the rate of change of the height?"*

Given:

- $\frac{dV}{dt} = 7.2 \textrm{ ft}^3/s$
- $b = 2r = \frac{3}{7} h$
- want $\frac{dh}{dt}$ at $h = 13$
- $V = \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$

If the base is $2r$, then $r$ = (base/2), or in this case, $r = \frac{3h}{7\cdot2} = \frac{3}{14}h$

- $V = \frac{1}{3}\pi(\frac{3h}{14})^2$
- $V= \frac{1}{3}\pi\cdot\frac{9}{196}\cdot h^3$
- $V = \pi\cdot\frac{3}{196}\cdot h^3$

Now to differentiate both sides and fill in our given values:

- $\frac{dV}{dt} = 3h^2\cdot\frac{dh}{dt}\cdot\frac{3\pi}{196}$
- $7.2$ ft$^3$/s $= 3(13^2)\cdot\frac{3\pi}{196}\cdot\frac{dh}{dt}$
- $\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{7.2}{24.379400...}$
- $\frac{dh}{dt} = 0.295 = 0.30 $ ft$^3$/s

I wish there were some easy to way to check my answer, short of working backwards with a different part of the problem as the unknown, but I believe this to be correct, as I've worked it out the same way 3 times.  Thank you!

Comment: The rate of change of $h$ should be in feet per second.

Answer (score 0):

Looks right.  Although when the problem says the "base" is 3/7 times the height, it may mean the radius of the base, not the diameter.  Because physically, a sandpile will not be stable with a height four times the radius of the base.